# Flutter: TabBar content not changing inside StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Code:

```
Widget _getLeases() {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: leasesStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();
        if (snapshot.data == null) return const Loader();

        leases = snapshot.data!.docs;
        checkLeasesProgress();

        return _showLeases();
      },
    );
  }

Widget _showLeases() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          tileColor: Colors.grey[200],
          title: Text(
            translate('leases.leases'),
            style: Helpers.headerTitleStyle,
          ),
          trailing: _optionSelected == "edit" ? _addLease() : null,
        ),
        Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              controller: _leaseTabController,
              onTap: (int index) {
                setState(() {
                  _leaseTabController.animateTo(index);
                });
              },
              labelColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              unselectedLabelColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                ),
              ),
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: translate('leases.finished')),
                Tab(text: translate('leases.in_progress')),
                Tab(text: translate('leases.not_started')),
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Visibility(
                    visible: _leaseTabController.index == 0,
                    child: leasesList(leasesTab['finished']),
                  ),
                  Visibility(
                    visible: _leaseTabController.index == 1,
                    child: leasesList(leasesTab['inProgress']),
                  ),
                  Visibility(
                    visible: _leaseTabController.index == 2,
                    child: leasesList(leasesTab['notStarted']),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Everything is rendered fine but when I try to change tab it doesn't do anything. I was using `FutureBuilder` before and it was working fine.

Edit: after removing `setState` from `onTap` I can see tabs being changed but content remains the same with same tab index. This seems to work, but not with the controller:

```
TabBar(
                  // controller: _leaseTabController,
                  tabs: [
                   Tab(text: translate('leases.finished')),
                   Tab(text: translate('leases.in_progress')),
                   Tab(text: translate('leases.not_started')),
                  ],
                ),
```

Comment: please post it with screenshot or video gif for better understanding of question.

Comment: it's just a tab not changing when clicked

Comment: I added a new update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trick was creating another `StatefulWidget` to have its own state:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class OptionsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const OptionsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  OptionsScreenState createState() => OptionsScreenState();
}

class OptionsScreenState extends State<OptionsScreen> {
  final bodyGlobalKey = GlobalKey();
  late var streamFunction;

  @override
  void initState() {
    streamFunction = delayFunction;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  Stream<int> delayFunction = (() async* {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
      await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      yield i;
    }
  })();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<int>(
      stream: streamFunction,
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('loading...');
        if (snapshot.data == null) return Container();

        // return tabs();
        return const CustomTabs();
      },
    );
  }
}

class CustomTabs extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomTabs({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomTabs> createState() => _CustomTabsState();
}

class _CustomTabsState extends State<CustomTabs>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              controller: _tabController,
              // COMMENT FOR WAY B
              onTap: (int index) {
                setState(() {
                  _tabController.animateTo(index);
                });
              },
              labelColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                ),
              ),
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: '1'),
                Tab(text: '2'),
                Tab(text: '3'),
              ],
            ),
            // WAY A
            // THIS WAY HAS NO ANIMATION BUT IT HAS DYNAMIC HEIGHT
            // SetState TRIGGERS STREAMBUILDER WITH TAB CHANGES
            Column(
              children: [
                Visibility(
                  visible: _tabController.index == 0,
                  child: const Text('1111'),
                ),
                Visibility(
                  visible: _tabController.index == 1,
                  child: Column(
                    children: const [
                      Text('2222'),
                      Text('2222'),
                      Text('2222'),
                      Text('2222'),
                      Text('2222'),
                      Text('2222'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Visibility(
                  visible: _tabController.index == 2,
                  child: const Text('33333'),
                ),
                const Text('This is a different widget. Tabs will push it down')
              ],
            ),
            // THIS WAY HAS NO DYNAMIC HEIGHT BUT IT HAS ANIMATION
            // STREAMBUILDER ONLY TRIGGERS FIRST TIME
            // Container(
            //   color: Colors.red,
            //   height: 200,
            //   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
            //   child: TabBarView(
            //     controller: _tabController,
            //     children: [
            //       const Text('1111'),
            //       Column(
            //         children: const [
            //           Text('2222'),
            //           Text('2222'),
            //           Text('2222'),
            //           Text('2222'),
            //         ],
            //       ),
            //       const Text('3333'),
            //     ],
            //   ),
            // ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```