# create a Sliverlist with streamBuilder firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am tryng to implement a SliverList within a CustomScrollView to get data from firebase, but what i did until, it works but now it's not right, and I cannot pass "document.length" to the `childcount`.
Any suggestions?

```
body: CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
     SliverAppBar(
         pinned: true,
        title: const Text('cookbook').tr(),
        elevation: 3,
        expandedHeight: 196,
        surfaceTintColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
        stretch: true,
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),),
       
        flexibleSpace:
        FlexibleSpaceBar(
          background: Image.asset('assets/background_cookbook.jpg',
            fit: BoxFit.cover)
          ,)
    ),
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
            return StreamBuilder<dynamic>(
              stream: _services.userRef
                  .doc(_services.getUserID())
                  .collection('books')
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {

                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
                if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.docs.isEmpty) {
                 ....
                }
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'An error occurred',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the `SliverList` and `StreamBuilder` widgets the wrong way around.

In order to render a `SliverList` with data, you need to have that data available - and the `StreamBuilder` is responsible for that. So you should use the `StreamBuilder` as the outer widget, and then when it `hasData` you can render a `SliverList` with that data.

Comment: I also tried your solution, StreamBuilder > SliverList > SliverChildBuildDelegate > return Column...
and I got this error:
"A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderErrorBox"

Comment: I also tried this, but then the List has strange behaviour when scrolling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71233618/a-renderviewport-expected-a-child-of-type-rendersliver-but-received-a-child-of-t

Comment: Those sound like different problems, not related to the order of loading the data anymore.

Comment: right, then trying your solution, I got this error: "A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderErrorBox", any idea? thanks a lot!

Comment: Could it be that you need to pull the `StreamBuilder` event further up in the widget hierarchy?